# How to get Python code to work with C++ App?

Tags: c++, python, string

I have the following python 3 file:

```
import base64
import xxx

str = xxx.GetString()
str2 = base64.b64encode(str.encode())
str3 = str2.decode()
print str3
```

xxx is a module exported by some C++ code. This script does not work because calling Py_InitModule on this script returns NULL. The weird thing is if I create a stub xxx.py in the same directory

```
def GetString() :
    return "test"
```

and run the original script under python.exe, it works and outputs the base64 string. My question is why doesn't it like the return value of xxx.GetString? In the C++ code, it returns a string object. I hope I have explained my question well enough... this is a strange error.

Comment: This question can't be answered unless you post your C++ code.  The error is there.  There's nothing wrong with your Python code.

Comment: @George: Please add the tag name "C++"... Also, please post your c++ code...

Comment: Fixed the tag. I'll try to add the code as soon as I can.

Comment: Also, I have another script that uses the re module and it works with my code... but this doesn't. Could Unicode have anything to do with it?

Comment: Er, you seem to have added that you are using Python 3. Is it true? If yes, you should first try to execute the script using Python 3 (you'll see that it will fail due to various issues, which you will have to fix before going further). Really, it proves how important it is to give detailed information about your problem; otherwise we're just wasting our time.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just played around with the python script a bit more... and now it works. I have no idea why. I just renamed some variables or something. I have access to my dev. pc now, so if you want the c++ code still, I can post it.

Comment: Well if it works please mark the issue as closed :) Thanks.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Py_InitModule() is for *initializing* extension modules written in C, which is not what you are looking for here. If you want to import a module from C, there is a wealth of functions available in the C API: http://docs.python.org/c-api/import.html

But if your aim is really to run a script rather than import a module, you could also use one of the PyRun_XXX() functions described here: http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html

Comment: The latter is what I intended but it still doesn't run... I am wondering if it has anything to do with GetString returning a ASCII string instead of Unicode.

Comment: Here it is:

  
    return  Py_BuildValue("s","test");

Comment: This still doesnt make a lot of sense! Please post the code that is using the result from Py_BuildValue(). Don't assume that giving some partial and elliptic information about what you are trying to do is sufficient for us to diagnose your problem precisely!

Answer (score 1):

I know everybody says this...but:
Boost has an awesome library for exposing classes to python and getting data to and fro. If you're having problems, and looking for alternatives is an option I'd highly recommend the boost python library of the C interface. I've used them both, boost wins hands down imo.

Answer (score 0):

Er... You have to investigate why Py_InitModule returns NULL. Posting the Python code using that module won't help.

Comment: I don't know why it returns NULL - nothing is printed to the console.

Oh wait. I see what you're saying. NULL is returned when I try to load the script above with Py_InitModule, not some other module.